# как список параметров из терминала заключить в рамку

Tags: bash, macos, chat

Есть задача, написать такой код, который будет считывать параметры из терминала и добавлять вокруг рамку. Следующую строку

```
sh f1.sh 1 23 456 7890
```

будет преобразовывать к виду

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент есть вот такой код, но он не работает.

```
n= cat file1.txt \
 | awk '{ print length }' | sort -n | tail -1
                        #максимальная длина строки
#repeat $n printf "*"       #repeat: command not found
for i in {1..$n}; do echo "*"; done 

while read xxx; 
do 
    sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,$n\}$/ & /;ta'
                        #центрировать  весь текст посередине столбца
    sed 's/^/\* /' && sed 's/$/ \*/'        
done <file1.txt
```

Что не так с кодом и как настроить вывод введенных параметров в командную строку (а не из файла)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть хорошее практическое правило: если в коде появляется sed или awk, то значит что-то делается неправильно.

```
printf " |||||| \n"
printf "| %-4.4s |\n" "${@}"
printf " |||||| \n"
```